# Запятая при однородных членах, соединенных синонимическими союзами

Tags: пунктуация, союзы

Нужно ли ставить запятую между однородными члеными предложения, если между ними используются синонимические союзы (например, *или* и *либо*).

Это должно произойти либо завтра(,) или послезавтра.

Я понимаю, что такая конструкция звучит неестественно, однако приходится иметь дело с чужим текстом, который нельзя изменить. Спасибо!

Comment: А если в чужом тексте явная ошибка, почему ее нельзя исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > *Я понимаю, что такая конструкция звучит неестественно, однако приходится иметь дело с чужим текстом, который нельзя изменить.*

Но вы вправе отказаться ставить знаки препинания в явно нерусской фразе. Нет?

Answer (score 2):

Несмотря на то, что в предложении допущена ошибка с повторяющимся союзом, тем не менее, если все же надо оставить союз в таком виде, то запятая нужна. Здесь действует правило при повторяющихся союзах.

Ср.: С чужими я либо робел, либо важничал (М. Г.);